# How should I deal with namespace and classname collisions

Tags: c#, name-collision

My program has a Model Foo and a namespace that I want to also call Foo. They both make sense to me, but I want to avoid namespace and classname collisions.

**Which one should I change?** The namespace App.Foo or the Model App.Models.Foo?

Note: I'm using mvvm structure so I have binding code in the namespace App.Foo which uses App.Models.Foo in many places, therefore causing collisions unless I specify Models.Foo everytime (which is ugly).

Comment: If we had the actual names, it would probably still be opinion based but as it is, this is also too abstract. "I have two things called Foo, which one should I rename?" - how should we know? It'll come down to whichever one you can come up with a better alternative name for.

Comment: I see, thanks for your input Damien. I've chosen for now to google synonyms for my Foo and rename the namespace as that would be easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt for renaming `App.Model.Foo` to `FooModel`, as you would likely have at least one `FooView` and `FooViewModel`...

Given your short description, Foo seems to be rather a high-level concept, and FooModel would be the "data" representation of this concept...

My 2 cents